# Chrome Web Store 'You don't have access to licensing data for App ID:'

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-chrome-app, chrome-web-store

I have an offline Chrome Web App I want to sell through the web store.

It has a server backend.  I'd like the server to check license data.  How do I do that?

Here's the [API](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/api_index).  Here's a [Java HowTo](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/one_time_payments#update-manifest).  Here's a [OAuth-JWT lib for nodejs](https://github.com/extrabacon/google-oauth-jwt).  I made a new client-id as described in the lib's readme.

I get this response:

```
{ error: 
   { errors: [ [Object] ],
     code: 403,
     message: 'You don\'t have access to licensing data for App ID: aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'
   }
}
```

How do I access license data for my app, in my server?

Mike

Here's the code:

```
var appId = 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa';
var userId = '1111111111111111111111';


// obtain a JWT-enabled version of request
var request = require('google-oauth-jwt').requestWithJWT();


request({
  url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/chromewebstore/v1.1/licenses/'+appId+'/'+userId,
  jwt: {
    // use the email address of the service account, as seen in the API console
    email: '11111111111-aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa@developer.gserviceaccount.com',
    // use the PEM file we generated from the downloaded key
    keyFile: 'config/keys/app-11111111111111.pem',
    // specify the scopes you wish to access - each application has different scopes
    scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/chromewebstore.readonly']
  }
}, function (err, res, body) {
    console.log(JSON.parse(body));
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've spent way to much time on this and other small problems with the Chrome Webstore.  Going with Stripe.com, Braintree, or similar.